# Gestión automática de ficheros

Tags: php, mysql, archivo

A ver si alguien puede darme alguna idea/pista:
Tengo una tabla Mysql que almacena datos de clientes. Entre ellos, documentos identificados por un código. Por ejemplo, el código CD1200 puede tener 1 o varios ficheros que deben ir asociados. Los ficheros son PDf generados por una aplicación que los guarda en una carpeta que crea cada día con el número de día, por lo que puedo tener la carpeta 0101 con los ficheros dentro abcsdCD1200asd.pdf, 123CD1200ad.pdf, qwertyCD2100.pdf, tr5top2100oir.pdf. Lo que necesito es:
Tengo la tabla con lo snombre de clientes, y todos los días se suben los registros correspondientes a ellos, donde el código de los ejemplos CD1200 sería de un 1 cliente y el CD2100 sería de otro. Cada día puede haber 1 o varios ficheros generados con esa cadena en el nombre. Lo que busco es que, de alguna forma, pueda leer los nombres de los ficheros, y cuando encuentre la cadena que va asociada a cada cliente, le permita asociar sus ficheros y que solo vea sus ficheros. HAsta ahora se hace manualmente, pero es un emgorro diario si hay 200 ficheros. Es decir, no busco por contenido del fichero, sino por coincidencia de cartéres en el nombre del fichero, que nunca es igual. Si encuentra la cadena del código, lo debería asociar a ese registro en la tabla.

Buscando por google, encontré esto que en principio de partida me sirve, pero me sube los ficheros uno a uno, y debería poder subir varios a la vez.

INDEX.PHP

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cargar Ficheros</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css'>
<style>
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h4>Agregar Nueva Descarga</h4>
    <hr style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="content"> </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Cargar Ficheros</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <form method="POST" action="CargarFicheros.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
                <input required="" type="file" name="file" id="exampleInputFile">
              </label>
              
</div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cargar Fichero</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
<!--tabla-->
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Descargas Disponibles</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
   
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="7%">#</th>
      <th width="70%">Nombre del Archivo</th>
      <th width="13%">Descargar</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
$archivos = scandir("subidas");
$num=0;
for ($i=2; $i<count($archivos); $i++)
{$num++;
?>
<p>  
 </p>
         
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $num;?></th>
      <td><?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?></td>
      <td><a title="Descargar Archivo" href="subidas/<?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?>" download="<?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?>" style="color: blue; font-size:18px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a></td>
      
    </tr>
 <?php }?> 

  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Fin tabla--> 
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CARGARFICHEROS.PHP

```
<?php

// Cómo subir el archivo
$fichero = $_FILES["file"];

// Cargando el fichero en la carpeta "subidas"
move_uploaded_file($fichero["tmp_name"], "subidas/".$fichero["name"]);

// Redirigiendo hacia atrás
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

Con esto, de momento, veo que puedo subir fichero. Necesitaría saber como subir varios a la vez, y luego, una vez subidos, ver como hago para que cuando cada usuario entre, solo pueda ver/descargar los ficheros que le corresponden. Entiendo que debería poder asociarles sus ficheros con una consulta que asocie el usuario y la cadena con el código del nombre del fichero que les corresponde a cada uno, pero no sé como hacerlo.
¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Muéstranos tu código

Comment: Lo puedes resolver con una tabla asociativa que lleve control de cada cliente/fichero. Esa tabla podría tener quizá tres columnas: `cliente_id, fichero_id, fecha`  y las tres columnas podrían formar parte de una clave `UNIQUE` (para que no se repitan filas duplicadas). La columna `fecha` sería del tipo `DATETIME`. Sea como sea, debes mostrar lo que has intentado, qué problemas concretos tienes, etc si quieres que te ayudemos mejor.

Comment: Esto es lo que llevo de cara a la subida de archivos. Por otro lado, tengo las tablas de los clientes y sus datos. Me faltaría ver cómo poder subir variso ficheros a la vez, que se asocien por el código del nombre a cada usuario y que cuando este entre a ver sus datos, le permita descargar o ver los ficheros. Ahí estoy perdido aún.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil es que te guardes en BBDD una tabla con la relación usuario - ficheros, de tal manera que con una simple consulta sepas los ficheros de cada usuario.

Comment: Esto es lo que llevo de cara a la subida de archivos. Por otro lado, tengo las tablas de los clientes y sus datos. Me faltaría ver cómo poder subir variso ficheros a la vez, que se asocien por el código del nombre a cada usuario y que cuando este entre a ver sus datos, le permita descargar o ver los ficheros. Ahí estoy perdido aún